# converting a string from csv to a vector of numbers in R

Tags: r, list, csv

I have the following instruction in R:

```
y <- rep(1:2,each=3)
```

which I know that it generates a vector of 1 and 2:

```
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

How I can get the same results if I want to extract that information from a csv line that has the form:

```
[1] ",,1,1,1,2,2,2"
```

I have tried with as.numeric and is.na and I still get an empty list.
Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MatthewPlourde suggestion incorported:

```
> txt <- ",,1,1,1,2,2,2"
> scan(text=txt,, sep=",")
Read 8 items
[1] NA NA  1  1  1  2  2  2
```

Other option would be strsplit.

```
> unlist( strsplit(txt, ",") )
[1] ""  ""  "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2"
```

With adoption of Matthew's suggestion there is not a need to answer the question "how to convert to numeric?" .... but if you had a character vector it would have been ... now that you have separated into components,  use `as.numeric`:

```
> as.numeric( scan(textConnection(txt), what="", sep=",") )
Read 8 items
[1] NA NA  1  1  1  2  2  2
```

Another option would be to read with scan using the numeric format:

```
> scan(textConnection(txt), what=numeric(0), sep=",")
Read 8 items
[1] NA NA  1  1  1  2  2  2
```

And to remove the NAs:

```
> numbas <- scan(textConnection(txt), what=numeric(0), sep=",")
Read 8 items
> numbas[!is.na(numbas)]
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

Comment: thanks @DWin, but I want to transform the line that I got [1] ",,1,1,1,2,2,2" to [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2

Comment: @DWin +1. fyi, `scan` has a `text` formal.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde: I'm not sure I understand your point. My use of the `what` argument was the specification of a text format. But maybe your point was addressed by my edit?

Comment: @DWin my point was that you don't need `textConnection`---`scan` has an argument `text`.

Comment: Aha. Yes, @Matthew. Now I remember ... that was how `read.table` and cousins were given that argument, wasn't it?

Comment: I was curious why you chose `! is.na` over `na.omit`. Turns out the index way is slightly faster...surprising.

Comment: I learned `x[!is.na(x)]` before `na.omit(x)`. It's not really any different and I like using indexing.